# Spring WebFlux OpenAPI - override model/schema field name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm using Spring boot + webflux + r2dbc to implement an REST API Server.

The generated schema for a model is duplicating the same field with different definition (name, restrictions, etc.).

My model:

```kotlin
data class Extension(

    @Column("number")
    @JsonProperty("number", required = true)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{6,}\$")
    @Schema(description = "The number", example = "12345007100")
    val number: String,

    @Column("tenant_id")
    @JsonProperty("tenant_id", required = true)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{5}\$")
    @Schema(name = "tenant_id", description = "The ID of the Tenant", example = "12345")
    val tenantId: String,
)
```

Router

```kotlin
@Bean
fun extensionsRoutes(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
    return SpringdocRouteBuilder.route()
     .GET(
            path("/extensions").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
            handler::getAll
        ) { ops ->
            ops
                .tag(tag)
                .operationId("operation id")
                .summary("summary")
                .description("description")
                .response(
                    responseBuilder()
                        .responseCode("200")
                        .description("The list of all Extensions")
                        .implementationArray(Extension::class.java)
                )
        }
```

The generated OpenAPI schema for `Extension` model

```yaml
Extension:
    required:
    - number
    type: object
    properties:
      number:
        pattern: "^[0-9]{6,}$"
        type: string
        description: The number
        example: "12345007100"
      tenant_id:
        pattern: "^[0-9]{5}$"
        type: string
        description: The ID of the Tenant to which the Extension belongs
        writeOnly: true
        example: "12345"
      tenantId:
        type: string
```

I've two fields: tenant_id and tenantId but this is the same field in the model. Also note that the definition for tenantId ignores schema properties (like the required and pattern properties).

I'm missing some annotation ? Seems that i'm missing some annotation to indicate springdoc library that the field is already in definition.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem. I'm using kotlin and we need to add following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-kotlin</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

This is well documented at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation but i missed it.